# Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch

I have the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "brunch": "^1.8.5",
    "babel-brunch": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "sass-brunch": "~> 2.6.2"
  }
}
```

When I start my server with `mix phoenix.start`, I see this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
  at SassCompiler.compile (/Users/ryanbigg/Projects/elixir/twist/node_modules/sass-brunch/index.js:208:14)
  at /Users/ryanbigg/Projects/elixir/twist/node_modules/brunch/lib/fs_utils/pipeline.js:104:29
  at fn (/Users/ryanbigg/Projects/elixir/twist/node_modules/async-waterfall/index.js:19:24)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/ryanbigg/Projects/elixir/twist/node_modules/async-waterfall/index.js:58:22)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

What did I configure wrong here to get this error to occur?

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the Elixir Slack about this, and we found that using `sass-brunch` at `1.9.2` fixes this problem:

```
"sass-brunch": "~> 1.9.2"
```

Comment: Brunch has been undergoing rapid development lately, and everything `"brunch": "^2.0.0"` uses brunch plugins with version `^2.0.0`.